# how to change the content of a single div in ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have this angular code.

```
<div ng-repeat="item in items | filter:search" class="container">
            <h3>{{item.name}}</h3>
            <p>category:{{item.category}}</p>
            <p>price:INR {{item.price}} /-</p>
            <br/>
            <button ng-hide="showme" ng-click="process(item.name,item.price)">Add</button>
            <button ng-show="showme" class="ng-cloak">Remove</button>
        </div>``
```

Now what I want is whenever I click on the add button in one the div that button should hide and a remove button should display. I am able to do that but all the div are changing. I want to change just that div for which the button is clicked.

Here's my controller code

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);
myApp.controller('restaurantController', function($scope, $http){
    $http.get('apna.json').success(function (data){
        $scope.items = data;
    });
    $scope.showme=false;
    $scope.process = function(name,value){
        $scope.total = parseInt($scope.total) + parseInt(value);
        $scope.showme = true;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can assign a **showme** field to your items array , and give it a value to **false** , and in the ng-show and ng-hide directive use **item.showme** . Similarly in **process()** change the **showme** variable related to that item

Answer (score 1):

Your `showme` variable is on `$scope`, so each item does not get a new `showme` variable/property to hold its individual setting. So instead of putting it on `$scope` you can just set a new property on `item` itself indicating wither or not it was added. You then use that to test in your ng-show/hide.

```
<button ng-hide="item.added" ng-click="process(item)">Add</button>
<button ng-show="item.added" class="ng-cloak">Remove</button>
```

And in your `process` method

```
item.added = true;
```

Demo

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);
myApp.controller('restaurantController', function($scope, $http){
    $scope.items = [
      {name:"Item 1",category:"food",price:19},
      {name:"Item 2",category:"auto",price:39},
      {name:"Item 3",category:"software",price:13}
    ];
    $scope.total = 0;
    $scope.process = function(item){
        $scope.total = parseInt($scope.total) + parseInt(item.price);
        item.added = true;
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="restaurantController">
  Total: {{total}}<br>
  <div ng-repeat="item in items | filter:search" class="container">
    <h3>{{item.name}}</h3>
    <p>category:{{item.category}}</p>
    <p>price:INR {{item.price}} /-</p>
    <br/>
    <button ng-hide="item.added" ng-click="process(item)">Add</button>
    <button ng-show="item.added" class="ng-cloak">Remove</button>
  </div>
</div>
```